# Need to convert two columns one row of data into one column and two rows of data using Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata

I have 2 devices associated with one VIN. Currently, the database is set up with them in one row and separate columns. I need to wrangle the data into one column (per id/ sn number) and two rows.
I have tried to union() them, I created an array and then exploded the array (got close). The problem with the exploded array is I ended up with 8 rows and a cross-match of all possible combinations (removing the link between devices). I tried a stack (unPivot) also. The unPivot was missing VINs for some reason.

This image is what I am aiming for. The ID_1/ 2 and SN_1/ 2 are related and need to stay linked to the VIN.

[image]

Exploded Array

```
output1 = (df_test
           .withColumn('ID', array(col('ID_1'), col('ID_2')))
           .select('ID', 'VIN')
         )
output2 = (output1
            .withColumn('ID_1_x', explode('ID'))
            .select('ID_1_x', 'VIN')
            )
```

unPivot

```
unPivot_df = (df_test
             .select('VIN', expr("stack(3, 'ID_1', ID_1, 'ID_2', ID_2) as (other, ID)"))
              .where("ID is not null")
             )
```

Comment: I cannot use a for loop, they are bad for big data.

Comment: try this `unPivot_df = df_test.select('VIN', expr("stack(2, ID_1, SN_1, ID_2, SN_2) as (ID, SN)"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use [stack](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/api/pyspark.pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df.select(F.expr("stack(2, ID_1, SN_1, ID_2, SN_2) as (ID, SN)"), 'VIN').show()
```

or A `select` and `union` would work as well:

```
df1=df.selectExpr("ID_1 as ID","SN_1 as SN", "VIN")
df2=df.selectExpr("ID_2 as ID","SN_2 as SN", "VIN")
df1.union(df2).show()
```

Input:

[image: Input]

Output:

Using Stack:

[image: Stack]

Using Select and Union:

[image: SU]

Answer (score 1):

Other option

```
dataDF.select(col("ID_1").alias("ID"), col("SN_1").alias("SN"), "VIN").union(
    dataDF.select(col("ID_2").alias("ID"), col("SN_2").alias("SN"), "VIN")
).show()

+-------+---+--------+
|     ID| SN|     VIN|
+-------+---+--------+
|1097629|123|JF783J89|
|1044528|176|  62H86S|
|1023862|198| 98YAQ65|
|1039663|130| 58YH32H|
|2048772|278|JF783J89|
|2009365|294|  62H86S|
|2019781|213| 98YAQ65|
|2031675|268| 58YH32H|
+-------+---+--------+
```